# rails api with active storage returns a link for an uploaded to s3 service file to a non existing page

Tags: amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, rails-api

My rails API uses active storage to upload a given user avatar image to s3 service

storage.yml

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: eu-central-1
  bucket: my-bucket-production
```

It exposes the image in users_controller.rb:

```
def show
   render json: user_info, status: :ok
 end
 def user_info
   c = @user.as_json(only: %i[id email role username])
   c.merge!(avatar_path: url_for(@user.avatar)) if @user.avatar.attached?
   c
 end
```

The front-end built with quasar framework (vue3) when calling via axios it gets a link like

```
https://api.sometestpage.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--3ba88d18cd3d08bd920414a885e532ecbbdeca5f/avatar.jpg
```

witch leads to a 404 error.

Can anybody point out what is wrong, please?

My code (backend and frontend) works fine locally in dev mode (storing to disk, not s3). The problem occurs only when I upload my code to my server and try to run it in production.
I tried to use `@user.avatar.service_url` instead of `url_for(@user.avatar)` but I get an undefined method error.

Rails version is 7.0.8

Comment: Can you verify that `avatar.jpg` is actually uploaded to S3 via the console or CLI?

Comment: I can see that the image is uploaded to s3 bucket and that it is publicly accessible. I also checked tables active_storage_attachments and active_storage_blobs in my database and they have the needed data (key, filename)